# Dynamically Building Date from String Parse

Tags: c#, datetime, replace, text-parsing

I have a string in stored in our db which holds pre-determined data for some queries for our views.

e.g. an example of the string in the db is

> userid=3,name=stuart, etc

Currently sub in some special cases with placeholder, to allow me to dynamically set some data at runtime (without user input) such as

> userid={UID}

so when this is read from the db I simply do a replace on the string to sub in the data;

```
string.Replace("{UID}", User.ID);
```

Effectively allowing me to restrict the views and predetermine the data returned to them. I have been tasked now with adding a more dynamic approach to the dates.

We have additional date fields such and StartDate and EndDate, which up until now have simply had hardcoded date to restrict what data is shown;

e.g. StartDate=2015/10/21,EndDate=2015/11/21 (i.e. yyyy/MM/dd)

These need to be made more flexible so for example I canshow the current months data, quarterly data, yearly data, etc.

My idea ws to stick with the same placeholder type and add something like;

StartDate={-Days(10)} - for a StartDate 10 days before DateTime.Now

StartDate={-Months(3)} - e.g. for 3 months prior to DateTime.Now

StartDate={-Years(1)} - e.g. for minus a year from DateTime.Now

StartDate={+Days(10)} - e.g. 10 days in the future from DateTime.Now

I would then do a similar process with the EndDate.

EndDate={-Months(10)} - e.g. minus 10 months from DateTime.Now, etc

This would allow me the flexibility of then building near enough any date constraints. Ideally it would also be good to chain these constraints as well;

StartDate={-Days(10)-Months(1)-Years(2)}

What would te best way be of grabbing this data and then doing this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you just need the three offsets you've suggested (day, month and year which can be positive or negative), you can then use DateTime's AddDays/Months/Years methods to get the date you need and format it accordingly for your query.

E.g. after parsing these out of your string:

```
String formattedDate =  DateTime.Date.AddDays(days).AddMonths(months).AddYears(years).ToString("<database specific date format!>");
```

This example uses .Date rather than .Now so has no time element.

In terms of storing these offsets you can use a similar format to that you suggested, e.g.:

```
StartDate=1,-2, 4
```

As your three offsets.

Having said that, I suspect you'd be much better off having a table in your database with specific fields for all these filter options, rather than parsing out strings to get at them. In other words in this example you'd have three fields for day, month and year offsets. The advantage of this is you can do everything in SQL and you'll get more efficient and optimised queries. Of course it's possible you can't change this design and you just have to go with it but I would suggest you test your current approach for performance and db load as you could hit problems with it in the future.

Comment: I'm happy with the c# approach to getting the date, it more the process of parsing I want to try and make efficient and am ot sure how to approach. I appreciate it may be better using multiple fields too, unfortunately its an existing db and I am stuck with what i have. Additionally there are multiple filters so I couldnt really use this approach.

Comment: Added a little info about storing the offsets, are you OK parsing that kind of info?

Comment: I see sounds a decent approach, so I we could simply have StartDate={0,0,-20} for twenty days in the past, etc. That would work. Last issue would just be parsing the data out? As to keep generic I would like to not have to physically look for StatDate, EndDate, etc. I.e. any field coud use this as long as it uses this structure? any ideas?

Comment: Sure, so in that case presumably your existing code will do some of that for you as it's already supplying field={value}, you're now just changing the {value} part to have multiple values. You can use a simple String.Split to get the values and then validate you have exactly three. You can then use this to determine if you're filtering for a date or, if you have a single value assume you're doing a standard filter. Here again though you can see why using string parsing for this kind of thing gets nasty!

Comment: *If* you stick with this approach then you'd also want to validate and/or throw exceptions whenever you see an incorrectly formatted filter string. I'd really recommend you suggest changing this approach though, even if it's just for these new offsets.

Comment: many thanks for the input. Out of interest how would you make this generic with adding additional fields to the table?

Comment: To be fair to make it truly generic you'd lose some ability to optimise queries as you'd need probably a table of filters which itself would have a field for the field you're filtering! Although I'd be willing to bet that a high percentage of your queries use the same or similar filters and so for these you'd optimise, eg with a stored proc that conditionally ran maybe 2 or 3 optimised queries and then a generic one if uncommon filters were used.